# UIView і Gradient

Tags: ios, swift, view, app

Есть отдельный класс для UIView, чтобы можно было подставить в разных контроллерах. В сторибордах я подключил файлы к обьектам. Но когда я запускаю программу, то view на контроллере остается просто белым,  а должен быть градиент. Что я не так подключил или написал??

**GradientView.swift**

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    var gradientSet = [[CGColor]]()
    var currentGradient: Int = 0

    let gradientOne = UIColor(red: 48/255, green: 62/255, blue: 103/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let gradientTwo = UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 88/255, blue: 53/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let gradientThree = UIColor(red: 196/255, green: 70/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

    func gradientSettings()
    {
        gradientSet.append([gradientOne, gradientTwo])
        gradientSet.append([gradientTwo, gradientThree])
        gradientSet.append([gradientThree, gradientOne])

        gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
        gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:1)
        gradient.drawsAsynchronously = true
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

    }
    func animateGradient() {
        if currentGradient < gradientSet.count - 1 {
            currentGradient += 1
        } else {
            currentGradient = 0
        }

        let gradientChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
        gradientChangeAnimation.duration = 5.0
        gradientChangeAnimation.toValue = gradientSet[currentGradient]
        gradientChangeAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.both
        gradientChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        gradient.add(gradientChangeAnimation, forKey: "colorChange")
    }

}
extension GradientView: CAAnimationDelegate {
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
            animateGradient()
        }
    }
}
```

И  класс самого контроллера.
 ***MainMenu.swift***

```
class MainMenu: UIViewController{
    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabelMenu: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var gradientView: GradientView!

    //MARK: Override
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

Comment: Нужно это вью let view = UIView() добавить в class GradientView: UIView командой addSubview()

Comment: Я пытаюсь добавить , но у меня все время  падает программа. Куда именно мне нужно это вписать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать например так - сначала создаем вью и градиент, потом устанавливаем фреймы для них (в `layoutSubviews`, когда известен конечный размер `GradientView`)

```
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        gradientSettings()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        view.frame = bounds
        gradient.frame = view.bounds
    }

    func gradientSettings()
    {
        gradientSet.append([gradientOne, gradientTwo])
        gradientSet.append([gradientTwo, gradientThree])
        gradientSet.append([gradientThree, gradientOne])

        gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:1)
        gradient.drawsAsynchronously = true

        addSubview(view)
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, я добавил еще немного своего кода и все  стало как надо )

Comment: Когда я устанавливаю любой обьект на view, то он как будто падает за градиент, и его не видно. Подскажите, с чем это связано ?

Comment: @Mastlos оформите как отдельный вопрос, приложите код для воспроизведения проблемы